# Get status report from shell script to java code

Tags: java, linux, shell

Can any one tell me how to get status report from shell script to java code.
Use case : I run a shell script from java code and if I get any error in shell script(while running) then I need to send some message from shell script to my java code.

So how I can acheive that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way, but an easy way to do this is to have the shell script pipe error output to a file, which you then read by the Java application.

Comment: :D. good one ... I also thought that.but thats a really a bad way to do this.... if no solution found, then I have to follow that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) launch your shell script.

Once you build the process you can use [**getInputStream()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) which will give you the output stream from the Shell Script, then just copy the stream to where you want to go.

There also is a [redirectOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect%29) but I have limited experiences using it. I'm assuming it does what I'm describing above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -la")
// To get the error code (0=success)
int outCode = proc.exitValue()
```

If you need to send something from the script to the application executing it, you may be able to do that writing to `stdErr` in the script and using `proc.getErrorStream` in your java program.